# jQuery .wrap() without needed refocusing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I need to wrap input with div, but after .wrap() input blurred. How to repair it?

```
<input type="text">

<script>
    $("input").on("keypress", function(){
        $(this).wrap("<div></div>");
    })
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3W3W/

Comment: That would trigger `wrap` on each keypress, but I guess you are aware? Only looks like there could be a better solution to what you are trying to do ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an explanation of what's going on:

When you call `wrap`, jQuery is removing the input from the DOM. It creates a DIV element, appends the input, and then re-appends to the DOM. Because the input is removed from the DOM, you lose focus.

The easiest way to address this issue is to call `focus` after `wrap`. After the DIV element is appended, jQuery will trigger focus on the `input` element.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2PgR8/

This, however, has the issue that user13500 mentioned in the comments. That, the input element is constantly wrapped with in a DIV. You end up with a DOM structure like:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you type "cool"...so not every efficient :)

May I ask what the purpose of wrapping the input in a DIV? You *COULD* limit the `wrap` with a conditional check, like:

```
if($(this).data('is-wrapped') === undefined) {
    $(this).wrap('<div></div>').data('is-wrapped', true).focus();
}
```

If you had a requirement for it.... Here's a fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/2PgR8/1/